# How to create custom preview for content type in Drupal 7?

Tags: nodes, entities

I am implementing a content type called "Product" which has some 8 to 10 fields.
While creating new product details under that content type "Product" client wants the custom preview of the content.

The default preview while adding content is really weird and it does not look good.

I have searched a lot on google but there is no any contributed module available for it.

So please tell the way other than custom module to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Page Preview](https://www.drupal.org/project/pagepreview) may help you.